# Linked list delete node. Free(pointer) prints 0 in next node

Tags: c, pointers, nodes, singly-linked-list

Below is a delete node in Linklist code that takes head pointer and position to delete as arguments (position index start at ZERO in Linklist). And after deleting, returns a pointer to head.

```
Node* delete(Node* head, int position) 
{
    Node *p = head;
    if(!position)
    {
        p = p->next;
    }
    else
    {
        while(position--)
        {
            if(!position) head->next = head->next->next; 
            head = head->next;
        }
    }
    free(head);
    return p; 
}
```

Suppose list: 20-2-19-7-3-6. And position to delete is 2 (node 19 to delete, since index start from zero).

After deleting, and printing, it says: 20-2-0-3-6.(i.e. the node directly next to the one deleted prints 0)

But if I remove the line "free(head)", then it prints: 20-2-7-3-6  (correctly).

Please help and explain why.

PS: There is no issue when deleting head node or tail node. But any other node in between shows 0 in next node.

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger? Side note: How is the question related to C++, since in C++ you can't declare a function named `delete`, so it cannot be C++.

Comment: A pen or pencil and a pad of paper are the best tools for both writing and debugging pointer-related code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the dry run of the code:

```
20 --> 2 --> 19 --> 7 --> 3 --> 6
^
head

while(position--) // position == 2
{
    if(!position) // position == 1, condition is false
        head->next = head->next->next; 
    head = head->next;
}

20 --> 2 --> 19 --> 7 --> 3 --> 6
       ^
       head

while(position--) // position == 1
{
    if(!position) // position == 0, condition is true
        head->next = head->next->next;
    head = head->next;
}

            /-----\
20 --> 2 --/ 19 --> 7 --> 3 --> 6    // 2's next is pointing to 7 now
                    ^
                    head
```

Now `free(head)` will be executed which will delete the node containing number `7`. Now, when you print, you'll probably get:

```
20 -> 2 -> (reference to deleted node) -> 3 -> 6
```

I think this is undefined behavior that you are referencing the deleted node and it's printing `0`.

Comment: Thank you. Had just started coding back then and was a noob at the time of asking this :). Sorry for late reply. Thanks again!